# AWS API Gateway:Mock integration response dynamic header mapping values

Tags: amazon-web-services, mocking, velocity, api-gateway

Is it possible to use velocity to dynamically change the header mapping values based on request headers or integration request body mapping templates?

To be more specific, as mentioned in the [W3C CORS spec Access-Control-Allow-Origin origin-list-or-null](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header), I would like to implement the CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to return the origin host value only if its a match, otherwise return null. I know this can be achieved through a lambda function, but lambda introduces additional overhead and costs. Just wanted to know whether it is possible to use any velocity template mechanisms in the integration header mappings to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Enable CORS option from Actions for a api gateway resource to do this. It will create a mock request to handle this. Only thing instead of the '*' wildcard for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', you have to mention the domain name. Check the snapshot below.

[image]

You can get more info from [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

Comment: This always returns the origin header value during the preflight requests, regardless of whether the origin is a match or not. This is not the recommended behavior for production environments. I want more of a conditional approach, rather than the default static behavior provided by the wizards.

Comment: This isn't dynamic, as requested, you're still hard-coding http://example.com as the response.